# MS Access: Trim a leading character upon input into form field

Tags: sql, ms-access, field, ms-access-2013

I'm building an access database, and on my main form, I have a field called "PartNumber." I want to scan data (a part number) into this field using a USB scanner and barcode. However, the barcodes include a leading "P" that isn't actually in the part number, and only serves to identify what kind of object that number is assigned to. I would like to automatically remove that P when I initially scan the data, so that the database stores and displays the correct part number.

I thought about using a query with an expression involving mid() and len(), then setting the control of the form field to that field in the query. However, that won't let me change or input data in the form's table, so it's useless for any records not already in the table.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with VBA, in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox.

```vb
Private Sub PartNumber_AfterUpdate()
    If Left(Me!PartNumber, 1) = "P" Then
        ' Remove the first character
        Me!PartNumber = Mid(Me!PartNumber, 2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the barcode API VBA runs: update tables via SQL or updates current form record in VBA; updates in bulk or updates one at a time. Either way at end of bar code reading when updating field, simply use `Replace()` in VBA or SQL:

SQL:

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = Replace(fieldname, 'P', '')
```

VBA:

```
Me.fieldname = Replace(Me.fieldname, 'P', '')
```